# C++ Using strcmp() in Class on Private Member Data

Tags: c++, class, private, member, strcmp

I'm doing an assignment for class and am having problems compiling this code. I have used `#include <string>` in both the main .cpp file and the class .cpp file. The error is "‘strcmp’ is not a member of ‘std’" but I get it whether I use std::strcmp() or strcmp().

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
double temporary::manipulate()
{
    if(!std::strcmp(description, "rectangle"))
    {
    cout << "Strings compare the same." << endl;
        return first * second;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `<string.h>` or `<cstring>` for `strcmp` or `std::strcmp` respectively. `<string>` is a C++ standard library required for `std:string` and other related functions.

Note that `std::strcmp` expects two `const char*`, not an `std::string`. If `description` is an `std::string`, you can get a pointer to the underlying data with the `c_str()` method:

```
if(!std::strcmp(description.c_str(), "rectangle"))
```

or just use the comparison operator. This is the more idiomatic solution:

```
if(description == "rectangle")
```

Comment: @DavidPetersonHarvey See my edit. Go for the idiomatic solution!

Comment: Sorry for the redundancy, trying to figure out where to add comments and hitting the wrong places. However, this is welcome progress but now I get error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’

Any further thoughts are welcome!

Comment: Thanks! I was overcomplicating things. Much respect!

Answer (score 1):

This function becomes accessible once you `#include <cstring>`.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C functions including `strcmp` in C++ are declared in header `<cstring>`. Header `<string>` defines standard class `std::basic_string`.
So you need directive

```
#include <cstring>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#include <cstring>
```

...

```
    if(!std::strcmp(description.c_str(), "rectangle"))
```